# OpenCV download on windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv

I am very new to openCV and want to download and start using it for image processing using Visual studio! However I would be grateful if someone can give me a link for downloading openCV on Windows as there are too many links available

Thank you.

Comment: Really? Have you at least googled for "opencv"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an official page to download the recent version  opencv 3.2 [here](http://opencv.org/downloads.html). You are saying you are a beginner but in the future If you opencv-contrib download from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases) in github. And [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) you have instruction on how to integrate opencv with visual studio.